# PyQt4: How many lines are visible in QTextEdit at once without scrolling?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextedit

I have a simple popup that is just a QTextEdit:

```
popup = QtGui.QTextEdit()
popup.setMinimumSize(1400, 1000)
popup.show()
```

that I fill with text.
I need to know how many lines does it have at once.
Let's say I have 1000 lines in it but because of it's size I can only see X=50 at once without scrolling up or down. How can I calculate that X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case `LineWrapMode` is set to `NoWrap` (`popup.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.NoWrap)`)  number of the visible lines can be calculated as:

```
num_lines = popup.height()//popup.fontMetrics().height()
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve on @Luchko's answer: it's more accurate to take into account the margin:

```
doc = popup.document()
margin = doc.documentMargin()
num_lines = (doc.size().height() - 2*margin)/popup.fontMetrics().height()
```